# Passing SEXP objects between C functions using PROTECT and UNPROTECT correctly

Tags: r, garbage-collection

I have an issue with the Valgrind check on CRAN for a package. While I cannot reproduce the issue, I suspect I know what the issue is. A simplified example is this C++ file:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// what I currently do

// call a R function with 1 argument
SEXP do_work1(SEXP x, SEXP fn, SEXP env){
  SEXP R_fcall, out;
  PROTECT(R_fcall = Rf_lang2(fn, x));
  PROTECT(out = Rf_eval(R_fcall, env));
  UNPROTECT(2);
  return out;
}

bool not_ok(SEXP x, R_len_t const ex_len){
  return !Rf_isReal(x) or !Rf_isVector(x) or Rf_xlength(x) != ex_len or
    Rf_isNull(x);
}

// [[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]
double use_do_worka(SEXP x, SEXP fn, SEXP env){
  SEXP res = do_work1(x, fn, env);
  CharacterVector what("y");
  SEXP y = Rf_getAttrib(res, what);
  
  if(not_ok(res, 2) or not_ok(y, 1))
    throw std::invalid_argument("not ok");
  
  double out = *REAL(res) + REAL(res)[1] + *REAL(y);
  return out;
}

// what I could do instead?

// [[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]
double use_do_workb(SEXP x, SEXP fn, SEXP env){
  SEXP res = PROTECT(do_work1(x, fn, env));  // added PROTECT
  CharacterVector what("y");
  SEXP y = PROTECT(Rf_getAttrib(res, what)); // added PROTECT
  
  if(not_ok(res, 2) or not_ok(y, 1)){
    UNPROTECT(2);                            // added UNPROTECT
    throw std::invalid_argument("not ok");
  }
  
  double out = *REAL(res) + REAL(res)[1] + *REAL(y);
  UNPROTECT(2);                              // added UNPROTECT
  return out;
}

// or maybe?

SEXP do_work2(SEXP x, SEXP fn, SEXP env){
  SEXP R_fcall, out;
  PROTECT(R_fcall = Rf_lang2(fn, x));
  PROTECT(out = Rf_eval(R_fcall, env));
  // removed UNPROTECT
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]
double use_do_workc(SEXP x, SEXP fn, SEXP env){
  SEXP res = do_work2(x, fn, env);           
  CharacterVector what("y");
  SEXP y = PROTECT(Rf_getAttrib(res, what)); // added PROTECT
  
  if(not_ok(res, 2) or not_ok(y, 1)){
    UNPROTECT(3);                            // added UNPROTECT
    throw std::invalid_argument("not ok");
  }
  
  double out = *REAL(res) + REAL(res)[1] + *REAL(y);
  UNPROTECT(3);                              // added UNPROTECT
  return out;
}

/*** R
f <- function(x) {
  x1 <- x[1]
  x2 <- x[2]
  out <- c(-400 * x1 * (x2 - x1 * x1) - 2 * (1 - x1),
            200 *      (x2 - x1 * x1))
  attr(out, "y") <- 100 * (x2 - x1 * x1)^2 + (1 - x1)^2
  out
}

for(i in 1:1000000){
  use_do_worka(1, f, .GlobalEnv)
  use_do_workb(1, f, .GlobalEnv)
  use_do_workc(1, f, .GlobalEnv)
}
*/
```

which one can compile and run the examples using `Rcpp::sourceCpp`. `do_work1` and `use_do_worka` is very similar to what I currently do. However, I suspect that `res` and `y` may be garbage collected in `use_do_worka`. **Is this true?**

If so then `use_do_workb` `PROTECT` both of them again. **Is this a good and correct way to pass SEXP objects between C functions? That is, re-protect the returned object from another C function?**

Lastly, `do_work2` and `use_do_workc` is very similar `use_do_workb` but save one `PROTECT` call. However, it adds the burden that one has to remember to `UNPROTECT` which I gather can easily lead to a bug. **Is this version still valid?**

#### Remarks

I have tried to run

```sh
R -d valgrind -e "Rcpp::sourceCpp('[name-of-file-w-above-code].cpp')"
```

but this does not cause any issues. I have also tried to `R CMD check --use-valgrind` the package but I cannot reproduce the issue on CRAN.

The actually error I get from CRAN is:

```sh
==4144090== Invalid read of size 8
==4144090==    at 0x483EDED: memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5 (/builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.16.1/memcheck/../shared/vg_replace_strmem.c:1032)
==4144090==    by 0x1736C2AC: copy (packages/tests-vg/psqn/src/../inst/include/lp.h:12)
==4144090==    by 0x1736C2AC: r_worker_bfgs::grad(double const*, double*) (packages/tests-vg/psqn/src/r-api.cpp:353)
==4144090==    by 0x17367754: PSQN::optim_info PSQN::bfgs<PSQN::R_reporter, PSQN::R_interrupter>(PSQN::problem&, double*, double, unsigned long, double, double, int)::{lambda(double, double*, double*, double*, double&)#4}::operator()(double, double*, double*, double*, double&) const (packages/tests-vg/psqn/src/../inst/include/psqn-bfgs.h:148)
```

with

- [packages/tests-vg/psqn/src/../inst/include/lp.h:12](https://github.com/boennecd/psqn/blob/49ada2ab3f8a039bf4ed27f59a155a5617264cf9/inst/include/lp.h#L12).
- [packages/tests-vg/psqn/src/r-api.cpp:353](https://github.com/boennecd/psqn/blob/49ada2ab3f8a039bf4ed27f59a155a5617264cf9/src/r-api.cpp#L353).

where I know that the vector [has the right length](https://github.com/boennecd/psqn/blob/49ada2ab3f8a039bf4ed27f59a155a5617264cf9/src/r-api.cpp#L348) which makes me suspect that it has been garbage collected because of the `invalid read of size 8` error. The vector is [created with very similar code as in my example above](https://github.com/boennecd/psqn/blob/49ada2ab3f8a039bf4ed27f59a155a5617264cf9/src/r-api.cpp#L38-L42).

Comment: A long technical question like this would probably get a better answer on the R-devel or R-package-devel mailing lists.  But to answer your questions:  yes, `use_do_worka` needs to protect `res`.  Yes, it's a good idea to be consistent about returning unprotected objects and then protecting them again if necessary.  This isn't a requirement, but it makes analysis easier:  it makes your `do_work2` look wrong, whether it is or not.